# Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Data.Linq.ISingleResult<""> to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<" ">. An explicit conversion exists?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

My controller file contains as below.

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    CityNameList ct = dt.AllCity();   /*Returns Citynames. Used Linq to Sql Classes to retrieve from DB. */

    return View(ct);
}
```

And in CityNameList.cs file in Model

```
public class CityNameList
{
    public IEnumerable<string> CityName {get;set;}
}
```

Really tried lot fix the issue, but no use.
I am new to MVC. I need clear idea to pass the data to View from result of Stored Procedure in Controller.

Comment: Please provide the code in AllCity()

Comment: Could you add more information about your program and on which line you receive the error message?  I would assume that you're trying to assign a value of type SingleResult to CityName, which is IEnumerable<String>, but you don't provide much information about that.

Comment: @JDupont  -- AllCity() is name of stored procedure called through Linq to Sql classes and dt is object od data context in L2SQL Classes.............                One more thing do i need do change anything in CityNmaeList.cs file..??

Comment: @Auguste --in  CityNameList ct = dt.AllCity(); getting error..All i need is map stored procedure output to CityNameList.cs class to generate Strongly typed view..

Comment: Ct.cityname =dt. Allcity  () ?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're using LinqToSql. If the stored procedure returning the ISingleResult then you need to enumerate the result to get the data. You can invoke ToList() to convert the result to IEnumerable. Also it looks like

```
var result = dt.AllCity();
CityNameList ct = null;
if (result != null && result.Any()) {
    ct = new CityNameList { CityName = result.ToList()};
}
return View(ct);
```

Comment: @vendettamit--No use..same error getting like--Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<MVC_DAL.AllCityResult>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?).....All i need to map stored procedure output to CityNamelist.cs class for strongly typed view generation..

Answer (score -1):

Change CityNameList class properties to below:

```
 public class CityNameList 
   {       
       public string CityName{ get; set; }
   }
```

And add Another class to map stored procedure output to Class CityNameList like below.

```
public class CityDataContext
{
   DataDataContext dt = new DataDataContext();
   public IEnumerable<CityNameList> DisplayName
    {
       get
       {
           List<CityNameList> Details = new List<CityNameList>();
           var result = dt.AllCity().ToList();
           for (int j = 0; j < result.Count;j++ )
           {
               CityNameList city = new CityNameList();
               city .CityName= Convert.ToString(result[j].cityname);

               Details.Add(city);
           }
           return Details;
       }
   }
}
```

Where cityname within for loop is column name of table which will be returning after executing stored procedure in DB, And finally add Strongly typed view with Model Class CityNameList.It will be working fine....